# How to implement autocomplete in android with data being in cache and synced with firestore(java)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an inventory management application where the user can manage the data of boxes in their inventory which is stored in Firebase Firestore. Here I want to implement autocomplete feature for the name of boxes so that all possible names starting with the letter entered by the user will appear in the dropdown. I want to sync the name of boxes stored in Firestore in a document to cache so that number of reads can be minimized and the cache will sync with that document when a change took place in the document. I tried to find it but to no avail, any suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated.

Structure of firestore is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRVzu.jpg)
In case the image is not available

```
The Structure of the firestore is
CollectionName
      DocumentName
          boxes:{box1,box2,box3......}
```

Here is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/search"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/ll1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/category_text5"
        android:text="Select the category of box"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/category_spinner6"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_style"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Enter the box you want to search"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Name of box"
        android:inputType="text"/>

</LinearLayout>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/Submit"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Go"
    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
```

So when a user enters A in the edit text box @id/search_edit_text he should see a list of all boxes starting with A but the data also needs to be cached and synced to the firestore so that whenever a new box is added or removed the cache should update its value.

Comment: I think this article, [How to filter Firestore data cheaper?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) can help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.